# Does Stokes hold? (Manifolds)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be the manifold with boundary $ M=\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $\omega\in\Omega^0(M)$ a 0-form.
Suppose both $\int_M d\omega$ and $\int_{\partial M}\omega$ are finite.

> Does Stokes theorem hold? Or does $\int_M d\omega=\int_{\partial M}\omega$ hold?

I have no idea how to prove of disprove this and would appreciate any hints to get me in the right direction. Also I use this version of Stokes:

> **Stokes' Theorem:** Let $M$ be a smooth, oriented $n$-manifold with boundary, and let $\omega$ be a compactly supported smooth $(n-1)$-form on $M$.  Then $$\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.$$

Comment: How is it possible that $\partial M = \Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$? One should have $\partial \partial M = \emptyset$, while $\partial  \Bbb{R}_{\ge 0} = \{ 0 \} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for the comment, I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, if $\alpha$ is indeed compactly supported. say $\alpha(x)=0$ for $x\geq c$.
In that case:
$$\int_{\partial M}\alpha = -\alpha(0)$$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_Md\alpha &= \int_0^\infty \alpha'(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^c\alpha'(0)dx\\
&=\alpha(c)-\alpha(0)=-\alpha(0)
\end{align}
$$

considering that you assume $\int_Md\alpha$ to exist, it might also be true if $\alpha$ is not compactly supported. I leave the similar proof to you

Comment: I dont fully understand what $\alpha$ is exactly. According to me it is an element of $W^*$, if $W$ is a vector space and $M$ is the union of coordinate patches $A\rightarrow B$ with $A$ open in $W$ and $B$ open in $M$. Is that right?

Comment: @DannyRand No. $\Omega^0(M)=C^\infty(M)$, i.e. $\alpha$ is just a smooth function on $M$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was confused by notation, your $\alpha$ is my $\omega$. Why do you get the minus sign at $\int_{\partial M}\alpha$?

Comment: Well you don't necessarily get a minus at $\int_{\partial M}\alpha$, but since the orientation of $\partial M$ is induced by the orientation of $M$ the signs of both $\alpha(0)$'s are equal. If you don't want the minus at $\int_{\partial M}\alpha$ then reverse the orientation on $M$. In that case though you'd get $$\int_Md\alpha=\int_{\infty}^0\alpha'(x)dx$$ so then here too the minus disappears in front of the $\alpha(0)$

Comment: And why does this prove that Stokes hold for all $\alpha$ with compact support?

Comment: @DannyRandall because stokes theorem says exactly that $\int_Md\alpha=\int_{\partial M}\alpha$, which we have shown, since both sides are equal to $-\alpha(0)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still new to this subject so I dont fully understand terms like compact support. Does compact support imply $\alpha(x)=0$ for $x\geq c$?

Comment: compactly supported means that $\alpha=0$ everywhere except on a compact subset $V\subset M$. In the specific case of $M=\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ this is equivalent with the statement that there is a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\alpha(x)=0$ for $x\geq c$.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot :) So if it is not compactly supported, then $\alpha=0$ on a compact subset?

Comment: @user2520938 If $a(x)=2$ for $x \ge 0$, then does Stokes hold as well?

Comment: @Amontillado What is $a$?

Comment: A constant function. Constants don't have compact support and are smooth 0-forms.

Comment: Also if $a$ is constant then the integral on $[0, \infty)$ looks like it's $0$ but on the border is not, so it looks like Stokes doesn't hold in that case...

Comment: @Amontillado Wouldnt $\int_{\partial M} a=2$ and $\int_M da=0$? Edit: didnt see your last comment :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I also get. If that is correct then I think that would be a counterexample to your question. That's why I am asking

Comment: @user2520938 But wouldn't you be integrating 0 over an infinite interval?

Comment: @user2520938.Right. I was just asking. Though a non-zero constant gives infinite integral, a zero constant would give zero integral, and $d(2)=0$.

Comment: @user2520938 Not the zero function. If $f$ is a non-zero constant function then both $\int_M df$ and $\int_{\partial M}f$ would be finite, since the border is $\{0\}$ and $df=0$. A non-zero constant doesn't have a compact support in $M=[0,\infty)$. I don't see anything wrong with my argument.

Comment: @Amontillado Ah yes sorry you are right, forget what i said before. So the compact support condition is necessary. Sorry for the confusion. You're right that in this case Stokes' theorem fails. But this doesn't contradict Stokes' theorem, since compact support in indeed an assumption made in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @user2520938 Thanks for the help! Would you mind taking a look at these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016700/stokes-in-mathbbr2-manifolds

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016735/manifolds-with-boundaries-and-partitions-of-unity ?